# obtain a strictly increasing sequence of the elements of array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So the task is this:
You are given an array of integers. On each move you are allowed to increase exactly one of its element by one. Find the minimal number of moves required to obtain a strictly increasing sequence from the input.

EXAMPLE:

input_array = [1, 1, 1], the output should be
array_change(input_array) = 3

this is my code and it works fine, it counts the moves correctly but for larger arrays it operates very slow. how can i optimize my code to do the same but faster? or is there just a better and faster way to do it?
MY CODE:

```
def array_change(input_array):
    l = len(input_array)
    k = 0
    for i in range(1, l):
        while input_array[i - 1] >= input_array[i]:
            input_array[i] += 1
            k += 1
            if input_array[i - 1] == input_array[i]:
                input_array[i] += 1
                k += 1

    return k
```

Comment: can you share us a large input and the desired output for few elements...?

Comment: What tools are we allowed to use? I think there's stuff to do with numpy, but maybe you have to stay at basic python tools.

Comment: Seems like a 'merge-sort' division could work for this problem. Divide input in two arrays `[1,1,1,1] => [1,1], [1,1]`. Apply to each of them, and then 'merge' the two. I.e. `[1,1,1,1] => [1,1],[1,1] => [1,2], [1,2] => [1,2,3,4]`

Answer (score 0):

ok i just got the right way to do this.

```
def arrayChange(iA):
    c = 0
    for i in range(len(iA) - 1):
        if iA[i] >= iA[i + 1]:
            d = iA[i] - iA[i + 1]
            iA[i + 1] += d + 1
            c += d + 1
    return c
```